# Laravel selecting decoded json variables from multiple with

Tags: json, laravel, view, laravel-blade

Say I retrieved the following from the database by using Eloquent 'with'.

Something like Debitur::find(7)->with('teleponDebitur')->first();

Here is how the data is structured:

```
{
                    "id": 7,
                    "user_id": 26,
                    "nama": "Mr. Zachery Wisoky",
                    "alamat": "44967 Anissa Parkways Apt. 262\nSelmerland, MS 41916-7633",
                    "tanggal_lahir": "1997-04-19",
                    "tempat_lahir": "51697 Jakubowski Freeway Apt. 414\nLake Sydneeshire, OR 11599",
                    "no_ktp": "41",
                    "created_at": "2018-07-16 02:49:34",
                    "updated_at": "2018-07-16 02:49:34",
                    "telepon_debitur": [
                        {
                            "id": 21,
                            "debitur_id": 7,
                            "no_telepon": "6",
                            "created_at": "2018-07-16 02:51:17",
                            "updated_at": "2018-07-16 02:51:17"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 32,
                            "debitur_id": 7,
                            "no_telepon": "8701",
                            "created_at": "2018-07-16 02:51:18",
                            "updated_at": "2018-07-16 02:51:18"
                        }
                    ]
}
```

Then I decode the json:

```
$value = json_decode($data);
    @foreach($value->data as $var)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $var->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $var->nama }}</td>
        <td>{{ $var->alamat }}</td>
        <td>{{ $var->telepon_debitur[0]->no_telepon }}</td> ????
    </tr>
```

It was fine, but I have no idea how to access the value 'no_telepon' inside 'telepon_debitur'?

Comment: as telepon_debitur is an array in your json so you have write another loop to parse data like this:  @foreach($value->data as $var)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $var->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $var->nama }}</td>
    <td>{{ $var->alamat }}</td>
    @foreach($var->telepon_debitur as tel)
    <td>{{ $tel->no_telepon }}</td> 
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

write another loop..seems like telepon_debitur define as **hasMany** relation in your Debitur model

```
 @foreach($value->data as $var)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $var->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $var->nama }}</td>
    <td>{{ $var->alamat }}</td>
    @foreach($var->telepon_debitur as telepon)
    <td>{{ $telepon->no_telepon }}</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: What if I want to get only one, similar to ->first()?

Comment: you can used like `<td>{{ $var->telepon_debitur->first()->no_telepon }}</td>`

Comment: The other dev wants to use ajax to show data in a table. He did it by getting data from db, encoding it in json, passing it through ajax route, then decoding it again to show the data. I don't know why though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to access without foreach by going through `$var->telepon_debitur[0]->no_telepon`